# Songs developing a lag as they progress

Tags: guitar-hero, guitar-hero-warriors-rock

I am experiencing an issue with Guitar Hero Warriors of Rock where songs will develop a video lag that starts out negligibly small and gets worse as the song progresses.  For most songs it is not even noticeable, but there are a few songs in the game where the lag is very apparent and it really interferes with the gameplay.

The song in particular that made me realize this was an issue was "Do You Feel Like We Do?" by Peter Frampton.  I believe it may be due to the length of the song (It is about 14 minutes long).

The song appears to play fine at first, but as you get further into it (I noticed at about 8-9 minutes in) a video lag appears to develop and gets progressively worse until the song ends.  By the end of the song the lag was so bad that the audio and video was very obviously out of sync.

*I am playing on an XBox 360 using an HDMI cable for the video signal and external speakers for audio (Using external speakers eliminates any possible audio lag since the signal is going directly from the XBox to the speakers).  I have tested this using multiple televisions and have ruled out the possibility that it could be my TV creating the issue.*

I was wondering if anyone else was experiencing this issue and if anyone had a solution?

---

**EDIT:**

Thank you for all of the great comments!  Based on one of the comments it was determined that it could be the disc that was causing the issue.  The only two things in my setup I have not been able to swap out and eliminate as the problem were the disc and the Xbox 360 itself, so I figured the next step would be to go out and purchase a new disc.  I bought a brand new copy too so I could be sure it was not scratched or damaged in any way.

The new disc arrived today and unfortunately the problem seems to continue even with a completely different disc...  So the disc itself is not the problem.

> So here is what I propose...
>
> I'm obviously not going to just go out and buy a new Xbox 360 when it may not even be the problem so my next guess is that this may be a bug within Guitar Hero Warriors of Rock itself.  Since this song is so outrageously long (like really... it drags on and on...) it is probably not played very often (even by people who play the game all the time like me).  If this song did have a bug, it is quite possible that it would go completely unnoticed by most of the Guitar Hero community.
>
> I was wondering if anyone on this site has Guitar Hero Warriors of Rock for the Xbox 360 and is good enough to play the song "Do You Feel Like We Do?" by Peter Frampton on expert difficulty? (I have only tried it on expert and to be honest I don't know if i have the patience to sit through the whole thing on a lower difficulty).
>
> ***If someone could test this out on their own Xbox, with their own TV and verify that the lag does not happen for them... or confirm that it does... I would greatly appreciate it!***
>
> *...If you can't do expert I would guess that the problem still occurs at lower difficulties... Feel free to give it a try and report your findings but **please also report the difficulty you played the song on** just to be thorough ;) ...*
>
> I would really like to know if there is something wrong with my Xbox or if this could be a bug that is inherent within the game itself.

Comment: Not an answer, but the fact that you're using external speakers does not rule out the possibility that it's your TV creating the issue. If the sound was going through the TV, the TV would most likely adjust the audio latency to be consistent with video latency, if for some reason it isn't consistent. With external speakers, there's nothing the TV can do with audio to compensate for the video. Just my two cents.
Is the next song out of sync from the start after you've played the long song?

Comment: No, the next song will start perfectly in sync.  Also if I try and put the audio through the TV there is a noticeable lag right at the start.  External speakers are definitely the way to go.  Look at the setup guide for Rocksmith or Bandfuse, those games explain why it is better to use external speakers.  The way I ruled out the TV being the problem is by trying it on multiple TVs.  I get the same results using two different TVs.   I guess it technically could still be the TV, but I find it highly unlikely two totally different TVs would have the same result if the TV was the problem.

Comment: I just purchased a 4K TV and assumed the issue was being caused by the TV taking processing time to upscale the graphics to 4k, but then I went back and tried it on my old 1080p TV and saw the same results.

Comment: I know and fully understand why external speakers are better to reduce audio latency, but it wouldn't do anything to help combat audio/video going out of sync. The game has audio latency calibration somewhere in the settings, perhaps you should try setting the audio through TV, calibrate the latency offset and then see if the problem persists. The most likely culprit for your issue is the xbox itself, since it probably doesn't have the resources to run the song for so long. I assume it's the audio that gets ahead of the video, right?

Comment: Yes, the audio is getting ahead of the video, but you would think that the Xbox would have the capability to play a game correctly that was specifically designed to run...  Calibrating the lag has no useful effect since there really is no lag at the start of the song.  The issue is that the lag gets worse as the song progresses which simply calibrating the lag won't solve.

Comment: Calibrating the lag is useful if you run the sound through the TV as I said you should do for troubleshooting purposes.
After searching up some info, it seems that a couple of people on the inter have experienced the same issue and replacing the disk fixed the out of sync problem, which, considering how xbox works, seems like a real possibility.

Comment: supposedly, if you pause the game, the video will catch up and get back in sync with audio, so if nothing else works, you can try that.

Comment: I've tried pausing, that doesn't seem to fix it. And I have tried with sound through the TV in the past, but even after calibrating the lag the game just doesn't feel like it plays right.

Comment: I have noticed a few spots in other songs where they play strangely, like the notes are blurry for a few seconds and then it fixes itself.  This seems to happen consistently at the same spots of the same songs so that would support the idea of the disk being bad.  The disk appears to be in perfect condition with no scratches at all, but I suppose I could drop another $15 to test if replacing the disk solves the problem.

Comment: I just purchased a new disk (in brand new condition so it should work).  It is expected to arrive by Jun 17 so I will let you know if it fixes the issue when I get it!

Comment: The new disc did not seem to solve the issue.  I have edited the question with more details.  Could anyone else give this song a try and see if they experience the same issue?

Comment: Your edit isn't relevant to solving your issue, so I've removed it.  All that should be in your question is the information about your problem.  Stuff about bounties doesn't belong in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This — specifically, latency that *gradually increases over the course of a song* — is an [issue that occurs](https://www.reddit.com/r/GuitarHero/comments/imkmxb/psa_if_you_play_on_xbox_make_sure_you_have_the/) with Neversoft Guitar Hero games* on certain Xbox 360 Slim motherboard configurations, and all Elite models. If your Slim power socket says **9.6A** rather than 10.83A, then it uses the Corona motherboard revision (introduced August 2011), which is susceptible to this problem. Unfortunately, the only way to avoid the bug completely is to use an Xbox with an earlier motherboard revision.

I have heard that you can work around the issue by pausing for several seconds to reset the latency creep, but I haven't tested that myself.

[image: Xbox 360 motherboard identification]

*Neversoft took over the Guitar Hero franchise starting with Guitar Hero III — for the Xbox, this means that all GH games besides Guitar Hero II have this bug. (No Rock Band games are affected.)

Comment: I don't know why or how you know this information... but thank you. That sounds like exactly what was happening lol

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything and it looks like the Xbox is the problem.  But to make things even more interesting it doesn't seem to be just my Xbox that has this problem...  It seems to be a problem with ALL of the newer black models of the Xbox 360.

When my old white Xbox died I got one of the newer black models from a friend and that seemed to be when the problem started.  I tried it with my old TV and with it directly plugged into the speakers so there would be no audio lag and even tried another disc... still the problem persisted.  I got so fed up with it that I asked a friend if I could try their Xbox to see if the problem happened with theirs too (they also had the newer  black model).  I tried it with there Xbox and the same thing was happening!  At this point I didn't know what to do so I gave up for a while...

But just the other day I found out that my neighbor across the street still had the old white Xbox and I figured since I tried everything else and found no solution it would at least be worth it to try the older Xbox and see if it fixed the problem...

So I borrowed my neighbor's Xbox for a night and sure enough it worked flawlessly!  It wasn't the 4k TV or the disk or any settings in the game.  Its the newer black Xbox.  It just seems to have issues with guitar hero for some reason.

Thanks for all of the responses.  I'm really surprised no one with the black model of the Xbox 360 has had this same issue and reported it... It's actually quite unfortunate because now I need to go out and buy a new Xbox, but at least I found the problem!

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not the disc or the Xbox. It's the 4k telly. I've just bought one, and it upscales HD, which often gives quite weird "speeded-up" effects on things like movies and adverts which are produced with a slowed-down feel. Last week, on my 4-year-old HD TV, it worked absolutely fine. Just tried it now on the 4k and it's shocking. Unfortunately I haven't yet found a way to turn the upscaling off, but I suspect that's what we're dealing with here.

Comment: It's not the TV.  Read the whole explanation and you'll see that I ruled out the possibility of it being the TV by doing a side by side comparison with my old 1080p standard HD TV.  The results were the same on both TVs.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 HD TV's tend to produce lag, same goes for 1080p HDTV's. Try turning on game mode if your TV supports it.

Comment: Yes, but I played the game for years on my old 1080p HDTV with no lag at all, the problem didn't seem to start until my XBox died and I got a new one.  Unfortunately since no one else seems to have the same problem the only explanation is that the XBox is the cause...  It may have overheated because my TV stand was not very well ventilated and that could be why it is happening.... It's unfortunate though :(

Answer (score -2):

Usually there is a option to sync the game and the video and the audio in the setting menu.I'm not sure if its in every game.